# Is it fine to submit a paper to a journal via arXiv without updating on arXiv?

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv

I have uploaded a preprint of my article to arXiv and it is published there. After that, I made several changes to it and I am submitting the same to a journal which allows submitting via arXiv (Physical Review E, to be specific). My question is, is it okay to submit the article without updating it on arXiv because I am submitting via arXiv?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is really the right venue for this question. But if I'm interpreting the [journal's submission FAQ](https://journals.aps.org/authors/submission-faq#ID%20names) correctly, they will download the article from the arXiv, so you should update the article on the arXiv first, and then submit to the journal. ("[The arXiv identifier] can be used at submission to automatically download files from the e-print server.")

Comment: They allow replacing the files during submission though.

Comment: Oh, I see. But it seems doubtful that the journal will actually update the arXiv entry to reflect the new version. So my take is that you should update the arXiv entry anyway. This has two advantages. Firstly, anyone viewing your paper on the arXiv sees the newest and best version of the paper. Secondly, if a referee decides to just grab the paper off the arXiv rather than downloading the version the journal sends, they won't end up with the wrong version of the paper.

Comment: Journal can't update on arXiv anyway. My question is whether is it problematic to use arXiv preprint number during submission when the two versions are not the same.

Comment: Right—and I think the answer is yes, for the reasons I gave. It may not be problematic in the sense that the journal will doubtless consider the paper anyway, and won't check to see if they're the same. But a reviewer may end up reading the wrong version, and that could well be a problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you do not want to upload to the journal directly? Also, how could the journal possibly obtain your updated version if you are submitting via Arxiv, but do not update the Arxiv version?

Comment: Interestingly, this is being considered as "opinion based". It is not. Updating on arXiv takes a day and so if somebody wants to wait for that time, it is perfectly fine. But the question is this: Does journal want the arXiv preprint number or the updated version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the answer is "no" and seems to be obviously so.

The journal needs the latest version of your manuscript.  The journal will acquire your manuscript from arXiv.  Therefore, you must put the latest version of your manuscript on arXiv.

In any case, there seems to be no reason *not* to update the version on arXiv.